# Can you use BOTH the name and id attribute in an HTML element?

Tags: html

Can you use both of the 'NAME' and 'ID' attributes in an HTML element?

Answer (score 2):

There is no general restriction on using both `name` and `id` attributes on an element. Unless specified otherwise, an attribute may be used independently of other attributes.

The `name` and `id` attributes have different meanings and uses. However, historically, the `name` attribute has been used in a role that is now better handled with the `id` attribute (which was introduced to HTML later on), e.g. in an `img` or `form` element, and it is declared as deprecated or obsolete in such use. The `name` attribute still has a completely valid and even indispensable use in controls like `input` and `select`.

There is only one case where the use of `name` and `id` on the same element has restrictions, according to HTML5 CR (clause on [Obsolete but conforming features](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete-but-conforming-features)): if you use both attributes on an `a` element, then their values must be identical. Thus, `<a name=foo id=foo>` is OK (though obsolete), but `<a name=foo id=bar>` is not.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can!

But **notice**: if you use the same name twice in a `form`, the first element will be overwritten.

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="mytext" value="A"/>
    <input type="text" name="mytext" value="B"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<?php
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7ym-da9

The `value` of the text-input `mytext`will be `B`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was pretty sure that would be okay.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "the value of mytext"? In at least some cases, both values are available.

Comment: @Alohci I updated my answer. Check out the fiddle and you will see what I meant. `mytext` is not an array like `mytext[]` would be.

Comment: Thanks. OK, that's PHP behaviour. Both values are sent to the server, but PHP selects the last one. Other server sides will do things differently.

Comment: No, it is completely correct to have the same `name` attribute in different controls. You just need to deal with the consequences, and this depends on the technology used for form handling. As such, such elements mere cause a name=value pair to be included into the form data for each succesful control.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: Sorry, I didn't mention PHP. How do you handle multiple input fields with the same name in PHP when the $_POST-value is overwritten?